# SSIS dtexec - The component is missing, not registered, not upgradable, or missing required interfaces

Tags: ssis, dtexec

I have a fairly simple control flow with two data flows. The first one reads data from an Excel spreadsheet using a source script component and stores data into a cache transform component. The second data flow uses a source script component to read a text file, then uses a lookup component to verify that the text file contained the correct information. The *No match output* from the Lookup is written into a flat file destination. If I run the package in Visual Studio, either debugger or execute, everything works. If I try to run the package from the command line using dtexec.exe I get the following error.

> Description: The component is missing, not registered, not
>   upgradeable, or missing required interfaces. The contact information
>   for this component is "Cache Transform;Microsoft Corporation;
>   Microsoft SQL Server; (C) Microsoft Corporation; All Rights Reserved;
>   http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support;1".

Other packages that don't use a Lookup component give a different error.

> Description: To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools
>   you must install Enterprise Edition (64-bit) of Integration Services
>   or higher.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and SSIS 2016, and the project target server version is SQL Server 2016. I'm running dtexec.exe from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\`. Running dtexec.exe from `c:\Program Files (x86)\...\DTS\Binn\` gives the same result.

Comment: Is integration services installed and the services is running?

Comment: Integration services are installed but I can't find SQL Server Integration Services on the services list. Something must have gone wrong in the installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try repairing / reinstalling SSIS per your comment:

> Integration services are installed but I can't find SQL Server
>   Integration Services on the services list. Something must have gone
>   wrong in the installation.

Comment: Yup, repair fixed it.